# VS2010RC + Silverlight 4

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to develop silverlight 4 applications in visual studio 2010 RC?
The official position of MS is we need to wait for silverlight's big update. I think it update will be on MIX10. But, what about any possibility to develop SL4 in VS2010RC now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this post](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsorokoletov.com%2F2010%2F02%2Fhate-2-wait-silverlight-4-beta-2-vs-2010-rc%2F)

Comment: I couldn't use the 'dynamic' keyword in SL code when using that hack.

Answer (score 1):

Their official position is SL3 is supported, but if you want to do SL4 development then stick with the beta, as the RC lacks SL4 project support (probably because SL4 is still too alpha  to be included in what is intended to be an almost production quality release of VS).

Reference: [ScottGu blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/vs-2010-net-4-release-candidate.aspx)